# Deploying to Google Cloud Function: Error message: 'main'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I deploy a Python app to Google Cloud Functions and got this very vague error message:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy parking_photo --runtime python37  --trigger-http
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                   
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: 'main'
```

I don't know what is wrong. Searching around gives no result. Anyone can help?

I believe my code layout is correct:

```
$ tree
.
├── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_burrowingowl.py
```

My `main.py` file has a function that matches the function name:

```py
import operator
from datetime import datetime

import logbook
from flask import Request, abort, redirect
from pydantic import ValidationError
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
from google.cloud import storage
from pytz import timezone


logger = logbook.Logger(__name__)
storage_client = storage.Client()


@dataclass
class Form:
    bucket: str = ...
    parkinglot: str = ...
    space_id: int = ...
    tz: str = ...


def parking_photo(request: Request):
    # Some code
    return
```

#### Update

Thank you for the answers. This topic is out of my sight, when I didn't receive notification from StackOverflow for a while.

Last year, I fixed it by just dropping use of `dataclass`. At that time, Google claimed to support Python 3.7 but actually not, that is why `dataclass` didn't work.

When you tried to reproduce this issue, maybe Google already fix the Python 3.7 compatibility.

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. Can you share your requirements.txt file ?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your function is raising a `FileNotFound` error, and Cloud Functions interprets this as `main.py` not existing. A minimal example that will cause the same error:

```
$ cat main.py
with open('missing.file'):
    pass

def test(request):
    return 'Hello World!'
```

You should check to make sure that any files you're trying to open are included with your function. You can `try`/`except` for this error and log a message to figure it out as well.

Comment: Along the same lines, if your function raises an AttributeError at import time, the Cloud Functions deploy will assume that your entry point is missing, even if the reason is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried to reproduce the error that you are describing by deploying a new Cloud Function without any function with the name of the CF and I got the following error:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py is expected to contain a function named function-test

I think it’s a similar one, since the error code is the same. My function was deployed with an error and later I edited the name by the Cloud Console, and then I got a correct deployment.

I would suggest to validate the function to be called in the Cloud Console and validate it’s correctly set.

Another approach would be to use the [--entry_point](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--entry-point) parameter indicating the name of the function to be executed.

Comment: --entry-point is required when the function name in code is different of the Cloud Function name. It's not the case

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on Dustins answer:
A similar error occurs with any error that happens when initializing the function.

```
OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py is expected to contain a function named function-test
```

The following snippet can reproduce this error. It turned out there was an exception in some additional initialization code. Therefore the function that should be deployed is never reached.

```
def init_something():
    raise NameError('Ooops, something went wrong')


init_something()


def function_to_deploy():
    return 'Hello World', 200
```

Make sure to handle exceptions in the init code.